# Can't write in an EditText, solution please?

Tags: java, xml, android-edittext

I'm coding for a project and I don't know why but I can't write in both EditTexts when launching my app in Android Studio.

Here is the code of my xml-file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFEB"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/log_in"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:id="@+id/username_login_main"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_login_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I looked at android:enabled, android:visibility(=visible) and android:focusable and they're all true/enabled.

Comment: i try your code its working fine buddy

Answer (score 0):

Try giving inputType attribute to EditText because inputType configures the keyboard configuration. Please check the below link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/plain_text_input"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:inputType="text"/>
```